# URL Params and too many if else checks in the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

An architectural query here I guess.

I'm building a shopping site, when a user sees a results page they can then filter by price, size, brand, store etc. The way I do this is I send the filters up to the url - this works fine. However -

My controller (actually recently moved this logic into the model) has so many if else statements its crazy. My current implementation has:

```
    ########   different rhs scenarios    ######## 
     if params[:brand] and params[:store]
        @products = Product.search_tank(params[:search], :per_page => @@pp, :page => params[:page], :category_filters => {:store => "#{params[:store]}", :brand => "#{params[:brand]}"})
     elsif params[:store]
       @products = Product.search_tank(params[:search], :per_page => @@pp, :page => params[:page], :category_filters => {:store => "#{params[:store]}"})
     elsif params[:brand]
          @products = Product.search_tank(params[:search], :per_page => @@pp, :page => params[:page], :category_filters => {:brand => "#{params[:brand]}"})
     elsif params[:price]
           @products = Product.search_tank(params[:search], :per_page => @@pp, :page => params[:page], :category_filters => {:price => "#{params[:price]}"})
     else
       @products = Product.search_tank(params[:search], :per_page => @@pp, :page => params[:page])
    end
```

It basically means I need to have every combination:

1) search

2) search + price

3) search + brand

4) search + store

5) search + size

6) repeat for brand/store etc!!

This can't be right, surely I don't have to program every possible combination? I recently discovered params.merge, which looks like at least on the front-end it can help me. I'm a bit of a noob, it makes me think maybe this is where design patterns come in.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks for all help in advance.

Comment: Everyone keeps telling me this. I keep clicking on the arrows, what am I doing wrong?!?! I'm not computer illiterate but clearly this is beating me!

Comment: Done! Didn't even see the tick. What a spanner.

Comment: can you show the form that sends in these params?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New solution:

```
options = {}
options.merge!(:store => params[:store]) unless params[:store].blank?
options.merge!(:store => params[:price]) unless params[:price].blank?
options.merge!(:store => params[:brand]) unless params[:brand].blank?
@products = Product.search_tank(params[:search], :per_page => @@pp, :page => params[:page], :category_filters => options
```

Comment: Chris - I'm going to give this a go now. If it works I'm going to feel pretty silly. I assumed (doh) that it would throw up an empty error, like nil objects/arrays.

Comment: Doesn't work. IndexTank is trying to process the strings, so I'm getting no results because it cant find brand "" or store "". Will keep working on it, thanks :)

Comment: posted a new solution, a little cleaner

Comment: Ahhh @Chris Baretto - works like a charm. Seems so simple! Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout Ryan Bates' screencast on "Refactoring & DynamicDelegator". It'll give you a good idea about cleaning this sort of thing up. [Refactoring & DynamicDelegator](http://railscasts.com/episodes/212-refactoring-dynamic-delegator)

Answer (score 0):

A better pattern would likely involve selectively adding scopes and look something like this:

```
products = Products.scoped
products = products.search(params[:q]) if params[:q]
products = products.store(params[:store]) if params[:store]
products = products.brand(params[:brand]) if params[:brand]
```